# CKeditor inline toolbar keyup event on dropdowns

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need every click on ckeditor inline toolbar buttons to fire a function and i use this to do just that:

```
document.getElementById("cke_FormLinePreview").addEventListener("click", setFormLineElementValue);
```

("cke_FormLinePreview" is the id of the element being edited)

The problem is when i press the options on the different dropdown lists (For example "16" on the font-size dropdown list) it doesn't fire my function. is there any simple way to do that? or do i have to addeventlitsner to every child element of the toolbar to accomplish this task?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every button in ckeditor toolbox calls a function like

```
return CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(3,event);
```

you can override this function below your CHEDITOR initilization code

```
var OriginalFunction = CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction;

CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction=function(n,x)
{
    alert("Called From New function");
    //put your code here for event Listener
    OriginalFunction(n, x);
}
```

this will work for me,
you can simply put alert to check functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but this would disable the toolbar functionality... i need to fire a function without losing the toolbar functionality ?!

Comment: try this new code it will work ,there was a syntax error this new code will work

Comment: How can i implement this to specific inline editor instance?

Comment: can you provide me your sample code, so i can try with inline editor

Comment: sorry for late reply, here is a working code for your solution [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPdBpJ)

Comment: Wow! Great! Thank you very much for that!